# What is the term for an 'archery course' that involves walking from one target to the next, golf-course style?

Tags: archery

When I was a child (15 to 20 years ago, so precise details are difficult to remember), my dad would take me to an 'archery course' (searching for this in my area has only yielded results for the 'instruction' definition of course). There were ~10 or more targets placed throughout a wooded area, where archers could shoot at one target, and then after collecting their arrows, move on to the next. Some shots went slightly up-hill or down-hill.

I know that the range I used to go to was shut down around 2005 (+/- a few years) due to complaints of near-by residents. This was in the South-West Ohio area. So far, my search results today only show 'archery range's in the style of lanes that archers shoot at a single target at a fixed distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target or archery walking courses, according to [Oro Valley](https://www.orovalleyaz.gov/Government/Departments/Parks-and-Recreation/Facilities/Archery-Range) - see [map](https://www.orovalleyaz.gov/files/assets/public/documents/parks-and-recreation/parks/naranja-east-walking-archery-course-distances-map.pdf)

If you [Duck Duck go "Archery walking course"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=archery%20walking%20course) you get a few ranges that have something like what you mention.

Oh, and the courses where you don't walk around a path are called "standing courses".

Comment: Ah, good call. That term also lead to "Field course", or "Walking range". from some organizations that have documents for safe practices, and design of these courses.
https://www.usarchery.org/resources/community-archery-park-guide-240319231011.pdf
https://www.fcgov.com/parks/pdf/archeryett.pdf?1363353194